# Word for someone who is jovial, but malicious?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I'm working on designing characters for a game, and the main group of villains consists of characters that have a two-word epithet in the form "The ___" where the word in the blank describes their personality or what they do (i.e. "The Languid," "The Reminder," etc.)

One of these characters acts like a trickster/jester, but in an uncanny and rather malicious way. (Think Batman's Joker or The Legend of Zelda's Happy Mask Salesman). Is there a word to describe this type of person? Basically I'm looking for a noun or adjective that includes meanings or connotations of "strange," "unpredictable," and "malicious."

Some near misses include "uncanny," "fickle," and "capricious." The latter of which comes closest, in my opinion, but doesn't quite encapsulate the connotation of malice or foreboding.

Comment: What's wrong with "The trickster"?  It sounds quite malicious to me.

Comment: Here is a list that may trigger something: fiend, hellion, imp, knave, rogue, scamp, scoundrel, villain

Answer (score 2):

I might pick one of **fay/fae** as alternatives for fairy that focus on the older malicious trickster version and make it clear you don't mean a cute Tinkerbell type. One might find "The Fey Fae" both appropriate and either awful, amusing, or both.

Answer (score 2):

The **malefic** (*adj.*):

1. Causing harm or destruction, especially by supernatural means

   > '*She was hypnotized by the spider's malefic eyes*'

   Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)
2. Doing mischief; causing harm or evil; nefarious; hurtful

   Source: [Webster](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Malefic)

The **scapegrace** (*noun, archaic*):

1. a mischievous or wayward person, especially a young person or child

   Origin: early 19th Century: from scape (see [scapegoat](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/scapegoat)) + [grace](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/grace), literally denoting a person who escapes the grace of God

   Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: *Mischievous* is in your definitions twice and not elsewhere among either the question or answers, so I'd make that the primary and +1 for it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use ***impish*** in this context.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impish

> impish
>        adjective imp·ish \ˈim-pish\
>   : having or showing a playful desire to cause trouble : playful and mischievous

Comment: But there is no note of maliciousness in impishness (playful is not something I'd associate with malicious). The most famous impish person might be Til Eulenspiegel.

Answer (score 1):

How about *the **malign***?

Definitely conveys malice.

---

**EDIT:** How about *the **devious?***

That definitely conveys malice, also strangeness in the form of perversity and has a connotation of joviality in the sense of sexual deviancy, for example.

Answer (score 1):

How about **deceiver** ? Dictionary.com describes [deceive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deceiver) to be,

> to mislead by a false appearance or statement; delude:

And there is a noun usage: deceiver.

Looking at you other examples you have used...

> (i.e. "The Languid," "The Reminder," etc.)

"The Deceiver" (to me of course) fits rather well.

Comment: I think I like this better than what I was originally going for. It doesn't quite encapsulate everything that I wanted, but it sounds really fitting for the character.

Answer (score 1):

Just googling synonyms gives a lot of synonyms, and classic mythology is a good source too. There are trickster gods like Puck or Loki or Pan. Or satyrs in general, which also has similarities to 'satire'.

But I would try to look for names that can have double meanings. For (bad) example, "the gagger". When he is first described in the game, people likely think of choking, but then they discover he isn't. This in and of itself is a gag and a mindtrick.  It's similar to how the Joker is both about jokes, and being a wildcard.

The kipper, which is a fish, specifically red herring.
The goose, and you're on a wild-goose chase.
The mocker; both one who mocks others, but also one that creates mock-events to distract.
The dummy, a smart man leaving behind false evidences.

Though all of these are more grouped around deception than malvolent behaviour, I hope it gives a different perspective on things.

Answer (score 0):

Two words come to mind: **"the unreliable"** and **"the treacherous"**

> - unreliable - (adj) "not to be relied or depended on" -  [D.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unreliable)
> - treacherous - (adj) "likely to betray trust" - [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/treacherous)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it conveys any joviality, but you can use the terms ***sarcastic***, ***sardonic***, or ***satirical*** to convey the idea of a person that is witty with a nasty side, particularly by ridiculing their target.

Answer (score 0):

**[Elfin](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/elfin)** - (With reference to a person) small and delicate, typically with an attractively mischievous or strange charm:

> “Elves are wonderful. They provoke wonder.
>   Elves are marvellous. They cause marvels.
>   Elves are fantastic. They create fantasies.
>   Elves are glamorous. They project glamour.
>   Elves are enchanting. They weave enchantment.
>   Elves are terrific. They beget terror.
>   The thing about words is that meanings can twist just like a snake, and if you want to find snakes look for them behind words that have changed their meaning.
>   No one ever said elves are nice.
>   Elves are bad.” - [Terry Pratchett](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/19190-elves-are-wonderful-they-provoke-wonder-elves-are-marvellous-they)

Answer (score 0):

Villains are often characterized as maniacal. You could call them "**The maniacal**".

> **Maniacal** *adjective*
>
> 1. :  affected with or suggestive of madness
> 2. :  characterized by ungovernable excitement or frenzy :  frantic

- [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maniacal)

Although, if you want to portray them as "tricksters" I would go with *deceptive*.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit like *[kokopelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kokopelli)*, a character in southwestern Americas culture that has several attributes, one of which is being a trickster. *Wikipedia*

Along those same lines, consider *shape-shifter* or *[Loki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trickster)* (*Wikipedia*)

Answer (score 0):

A troll

n.
1. A supernatural creature of Scandinavian folklore, variously portrayed as a friendly or mischievous dwarf or as a giant, that lives in caves, in the hills, or under bridges.

Comment: Why the negative vote, pray?